# mobile menu toggle button doesnt close

Tags: javascript, html, css

Having a few issues with my javascript code to toggle the opening and closing of a mobile menu. The below code works for opening the menu = style.height: 200px, but once the menu is open, clicking on the button doesn't close the menu bar (style.height: 0) as expected.

Anyone have some pointers as too where i'm going wrong with my code?

```js
document.getElementById("hamburger").addEventListener("click", toggleNav);

function toggleNav(){
    navSize = document.getElementById("mobilemenu").style.height;
    if (navSize == 200) {
        return close();
    }
    return open();
}
function open() {
        document.getElementById("mobilemenu").style.height = "200px";
}
function close() {
         document.getElementById("mobilemenu").style.height = "0";
}
```

```html
<div class="menubutton">
  <button id="hamburger" class="hamburger hamburger--collapse" type="button" onclick="toggleNav()">
    <span class="hamburger-box">
      <span class="hamburger-inner"></span>
    </span>
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you add the missing html to make this run correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're testing for the wrong value in `toggleNav()`

Use `if (navSize == "200px")`

Answer (score 1):

you can simply do that using **classList.toggle**

```js
document.getElementById("hamburger").addEventListener("click", function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
  document.getElementById("mobilemenu").classList.toggle('show');
});
```

```css
.menubutton {
position: fixed;
top:10px;
left:10px;
z-index: 999;
}
#mobilemenu {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 200px;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #eee;
  transition: transform .3s ease;
}

#mobilemenu.show {
  transform: translateX(0);
}
```

```html
<div class="menubutton">
  <button id="hamburger" class="hamburger hamburger--collapse" type="button">
          <span class="hamburger-box">
            <span class="hamburger-inner">Click</span>
          </span>
        </button>
</div>
<div id="mobilemenu"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

this is the faulty code:

```
    if (navSize == 200) {
      return close();
    }
    return open();
```

navSize will be something like `"200px"`, not `200` 
Since the if statement is always false, it only runs `open()`